# Configure WAF Application Gateway in front of App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

I have a VNET with two App Services and one Windows VM in Azure. They are in the same VNET using VPN point-to-site.

I want to protect this environment with a WAF and have read that I can use Application Gateway WAF instead of the very expensive setup with App Service Environment and Barracuda.

Could anyone please explain how I can achieve this? The closest I have found is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-application-firewall-portal .

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have created a Application Gateway now and I would like to protect my whole VNET, as explained above, with this Gateway using the new WAF feature in Application Gateway. I need help how to start using the feature, and how to connect the VNET to the Application Gateway.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone has the same question, starting from July 2017, the Azure Application Gateway with Web Application Firewall supports App Services deployed in the multi-tenant environment. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-overview).

More information on how to configure it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-powershell).

Comment: That's great, it doesn't explain how to then lock down access to the app service such that you can only go through the gateway to get to the app service

Comment: @johnstaveley - appreciate things change and this feature may not have been available at the time however App Service IP Restrictions are available on App Service. This could be the right solution however given that we know public IPs assigned to App Gateways may change, this may or may not be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Support for Azure Web Apps as backend pool member is not currently supported on Application Gateway. However for App Service Environment (ASE) there is a workaround possible. Refer to this blog post - http://sabbour.me/how-to-run-an-app-service-behind-a-waf-enabled-application-gateway/

Comment: Please use comments to provide suggestions including it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a NSG to lockdown the Internet calls and only allow calls from the AG to the ASE.

Comment: What is an NSG?

Comment: A Network Security Group: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg